# JNA - The data area passed to a system call is too small

Tags: jna, numa

Using JNA 4.4.0 against Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

I can invoke [GetCurrentThreadId()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183(v=vs.85).aspx) but [GetActiveProcessorGroupCount()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405486(v=vs.85).aspx) fails:

```
import com.sun.jna.LastErrorException;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface WinLibrary extends Library {
    public int GetCurrentThreadId() throws LastErrorException;

    public short GetActiveProcessorGroupCount() throws LastErrorException;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WinLibrary lib = (WinLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", WinLibrary.class);

        System.out.println(lib.GetCurrentThreadId());
        //8599

        System.out.println(lib.GetActiveProcessorGroupCount());
    }
}
```

Exception below:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [122] The data area passed to a system call is too small.
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:415)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:354)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:244)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.GetActiveProcessorGroupCount(Unknown Source)
at WinLibrary.main(WinLibrary.java:16)
```

Not sure how to interpret "The data area passed to a system call is too small" since I don't really provide anything to that method. Any idea?

UPDATE:

If I remove the throws LastErrorException it works, however Native.getLastError() returns 122, which is in [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
122 (0x7A)
The data area passed to a system call is too small.
```

Comment: You should extend `StdCallLibrary` instead of `Library` since that is the calling convention used by WinAPI

Comment: @cubrr Thank you but this doesn't seem to help in my case.

Comment: If you remove the `throws LastErrorException` and instead before the call add `Native.setPreserveLastError(true)` and afterwards `Native.getLastError()`, which error code do you get?

Comment: I removed the 'throws LastErrorException' and it works! getLastError yield 122. Confused but happy, please make an answer that I can accept :)

Comment: It's still showing the error though, weird. If you use getLastError before the method call, is it 122 before as well?

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's that much of a solution. What you've basically done is just made JNA *not* throw an exception when the Windows API has set an error code.

Comment: It does return what I expect though.
GetCurrentThreadId returns 1 and yields LastError = 0.
Tried with GetActiveProcessorCount(0) returns 8 and yields LastError = 122 .

Comment: If you call those WinAPI calls from a C program, do you still get those codes? This may be a JNA thing, given that you're not passing any parameters